# Determine the nature of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I determine whether or not this series converges ?
$$\Sigma ln(n)^{-\sqrt n}$$

I'm studying d'Alembert and Cauchy ratio tests but they are both inconclusive, the limits being 1.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the best way, but:

For $n=e^{2a}$ with $a>3$,

$\left( \ln(n) \right)^\sqrt{n} = (2a)^{e^a} > 6^{e^a} > 6^{4a} > e^{4a} = n^2$.

So for $n > e^6$, $\frac{1}{\left( \ln(n) \right)^\sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Hence the series converges because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ does.

Comment: Depending on how much rigor is needed... I'd probably settle with $\log n = \mathcal{O}(n)$ so $(\log n)^{-\sqrt{n}} = \mathcal{O}(n^{-\sqrt{n}}) = \mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.